# Ball is bouncing from the centre not the edge

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have coded a ball to bounce around on a canvas, however, the ball only bounces from the centre, not the edge.

I have already tried putting the radius instead of the x and y but that didn't help at all, as of right now I am out of ideas.

I expect the ball to bounce of the edges of itself rather than the centre of it

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
<title>Ball Bounce</title>

<style>


canvas {
border-width: 5px;
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #FF0000;
}

</style>

</head>


<body>

<canvas id="testCanvas" width="700" height="400"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var x = 300;
var y = 300;
var radius = 50;
var circleColour = "green";

var canvasWidth = canvas.width; 
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;




function circle(x, y, r, c) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = c;
ctx.fill()
ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
circle(x, y, radius, circleColour)
if (y<0 || y > canvasHeight){
dy = -dy;
}

if (x>canvasWidth || x<0){
dx = -dx;
}



 x = x + dx;
 y = y + dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 5.5);

</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already tried putting the radius instead of the x and y but that didn't help at all...

You need to combine the radius with x and y (or the canvas edges) to make sure the ball changes direction at all four borders.

```
if (y - radius < 0 || y + radius > canvasHeight) {
    dy = -dy;
}

if (x + radius > canvasWidth || x - radius < 0) {
    dx = -dx;
}
```